# How to get Intent of main launch Activity from a different Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm currently in a different Activity. How can I get the main launch Activity's Intent?

```
Intent launchIntent = getIntent();
```

In the above, obviously `getIntent()` would not get me the correct `Intent` that I need.

How can I get the main launch `Activity`'s `Intent`?

Comment: What do you need the main `Activity`'s `Intent` for?

Comment: I'm getting info like this... launchIntent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ARGS_KEY);

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Bundle;

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if (extras != null) {
       pics = extras.getInt(KEY_HERE);
   }
```

Replace pics and getInt as needed.

Answer (score 0):

When `Activity1` loads, grab the `Bundle` associated with it's launch.

When `Activity2` is launched, put these same extras into your new `Intent`, and pass it on to `Activity2`.

You can't just access an `Intent` from a different activity, you need to pass the information along.

Comment: The problem is I don't have access to Activity1 at all as far as I can tell because it is generated with Adobe AIR. The launch Activity is air.app.AppEntry however there is no file that I can modify. Is there a work around?