# How can you know what the main launch Activity is?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Newb question. How can you know what the main launch Activity is? Learning Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming this is for your code, check out the manifest.xml and look for this element:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

It should be contained within `<Activity>`  ...  `</Activity>` tags, and that `Activity` is the one that a user can launch from their phone.

Comment: Is android.intent.action.MAIN the main launch Activity class?

Comment: well, that is the `intent` flag that marks an Activity as the as main launch. Whatever Activity contains this `intent-filter` will be launched as a Main.

Comment: to clarify-- `onCreate(...)` is called in your `Activity` when the app starts.  Which `Activity` starts first is determined by this `intent-filter`

Answer (score 4):

You have to put the right intent tag on the activity in the manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: In Java is there a way to reference SomeActivity from a different Activity?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. SomeActivity referes to a class called `SomeActivity` which extends `Activity`. So yes you can reference it. If you mean referencing the currently running instance of `SomeActivity` then yes and no. There is no simple answer to that without getting into Android design patterns, at which point you should come up with a more specific question and ask it in a new thread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm basically trying to get an intent from another Activity. In this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931965/how-to-get-intent-of-main-launch-activity-from-a-different-activity

Answer (score 3):

The main activity can be considered the one which handles the initial screen of the application you're creating.

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="clustering.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" 
              android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/gene_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity android:name=".yourSubActivity"  android:label="@string/<ActivityName>"> </activity>
     ...list of other activities...
   </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

The main activity can be found and set in AndroidManifest.xml; look for

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

The `<activity>` with that action is the main activity (is the entry point for the app).

Answer (score 1):

You can look into **AndroidManifest.xml** in your porject

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

This will help you to find Launch activity.