# Apk installed on the device but I don't see it in the apps

Tags: android, apk, grid-layout

I wanted to tweak a piece of sample code from API Demos group - GridLayout0. For it I created a separate project and copied GridLayout0.java into it. Now when I try to see the results of my changes, I get in the LogCat is

```
Uploading GridLayoutSampleTwicked.apk onto device '0388920542204257'
Installing GridLayoutSampleTwicked.apk...
Success!
/GridLayoutSampleTwicked/bin/GridLayoutSampleTwicked.apk installed on device
Done!
```

Apparently the apk is successfully installed on the device, but I don't see the app in the list of apps where I could launch it from (Wasn't it supposed to launch right after it was installed anyway?)

I am a noob, might have missed something.

If it matters, while creating the new project Eclipse asked me about the "root parent." I had to link it back to the API Demos package because Eclipse wouldn't let me proceed with the new project.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/9933984/1289716

Comment: missing intent filter in androidmanifest.xml?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

verify if this element exist in your main activity on manifest.xml :

```
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Perfect it resolved the issue, this problem occurs when you choose LoginActivity to create an android application project.  It seems Android template doesn't add intent automatically.

Comment: I had the same issue when my "Main" and "Launcher" items were attached to an Activity that was insufficient to start the app

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this part was missing. Adding this and deleting the snippet I gave below launched the app as I wanted it to.

Eclipse generated this code and I don't quite understand what it does

```
<meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
           android:value="com.example.android.apis.view.GridLayout0" />
```