# My apps is installed on device but i can't find the device. Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

when i clicked on run my console shows  the log below but the application didn't lauched.

```
 Performing sync
[Automatic Target Mode: using device '4df17da40d645ff1'
Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
/projetname/bin/projectname.apk installed on device
 Done!
```

I searched and verify on [Apk installed on the device but I don't see it in the apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609224/apk-installed-on-the-device-but-i-dont-see-it-in-the-apps) example but this solution does not work for me.

Here is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="projectname.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.cyrilmottier.android.polaris2demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Copied wrap Google Maps Library/AndroidManifest.xml. -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <!-- End of copy. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="apikey" >
            <activity
                android:name="projectname.app.SplashPageActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="projectname.app.util.Settings"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="projectname.app.FBLoginActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.SlideActivityUp" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="projectname.app.util.Settings"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.SlideActivityUp" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="projectname.app.QRCode"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_qrcode"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
            <activity
                android:name="projectname.app.Connexion"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_connexion"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.SlideActivityUp" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
            <activity
                android:name="projectname.app.ActToast"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_act_toast"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.SlideActivityUp" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="projectname.app.projectnameMenu"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_page" >
            </activity>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                android:value="@string/app_id" />

            <activity
                android:name="projectname.app.ContactUs"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_us"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.SlideActivityUp" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="projectname.app.map.MapActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_map"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.SlideActivityUp" >
            </activity>
        </meta-data>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

what mistake did i made.

Comment: Go to DDMS and check.

Comment: ok i found the bug its the   </meta-data> 
 element sorry for this question

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `adb uninstall 'your app's packagename'` to uninstall your app and retry to install it.

Comment: ok i found the bug its the </meta-data> element sorry for this question